# AZure Logic Apps SFTP Connector reply 504 bad gateway

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-logic-apps

Can anyone help with this, I was trying to connect to a SFTP server with password, and after the SFTP SSH connector with "When a file is added or modified", I can view the directory in design mode, but when it's running, the response from SFTP server seems not right and the error is 504 shown as below:

```
        "error": {
            "code": 504,
            "source": "logic-apis-australiasoutheast.azure-apim.net",
            "message": "BadGateway",
            "innerError": {
                "status": 504,
                "message": "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond",
                "error": {
                    "message": "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"
                },
                "source": "sftpwithssh-ase.azconn-ase.p.azurewebsites.net"
            }
```

I can connect to the SFTP server via WinSCP or FileZilla and browsing, downloading without any issue.
Please help if you encounter with this and solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, I summarize some possible causes below for your reference:

**1.** Check if the address is correct. If you use hostname, try to use the server's IP address instead of hostname.

**2.** Check if the server's firewall is blocking the request from your logic app. Check the if the [IP of your logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#firewall-configuration-ip-addresses-and-service-tags) in the whitelist of your server firewall.

**3.** Check if the port you use in logic app is blocked by the server.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the server is not under my control and can be logged in via different IPs. and not only one SFTP server, all SFTPs that I want to visit are not working through. I will keep trying and updating once I found a way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but have overcome it in a sense. When looking at the deployment template, I found the following under triggers:

```json
"triggers":{
  "recurrence":{
     "frequency":"Hour",
     "interval":"1"
     },
     "metadata":{
       "L2RhdGEvZGV2L2luL3BhcnRuZXI=" : "['parameters(sftpwithssh_root_folder')]"
```

- Root folder is in Key Vault,
- Dev is "/data/dev/in/partner",
- QA is "/data/qa/in/partner".

On deployment, from the template, the metadata property is set from the parameters, but the NAME ("L2RhdGEvZGV2L2luL3BhcnRuZXI=") is not, and the name is the Base64 representation of the folder. (Try it and see.) So if you deploy the template to QA, you will get a mismatch between the parameter and the base64 name.

Edit the logic app code and change the metadata name to the base64 encoded QA folder ("L2RhdGEvcWEvaW4vcGFydG5lcg=="), save it, and everything will work as expected.

Comment: With an answer post like this please only answer. Your quesstion has to go into a question post - or maybe into a comment on your own answer.